# Dúvidas TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

Tenho 3 views que inflam contents de recycler view. Eu coloquei todas elas extendendo de uma `BaseActivity.java` para terem algumas funções comuns como NavigationView(Sidebar) e também o Toolbar.

Agora, eu queria fazer o uso de um `TabLayout` e obrigatóriamente eu tenho que usar fragment, pelo que eu entendi. Eu posso simplesmente fazer `fragment` dessas view passando o layout?

Minha dúvida é se tem como encapsular uma `Acitivity` + `Layout` num `fragment`.

Comment: Não consiguir entender essa pergunta. Mas o Fragment não pode faltar. Você pode até usar o mesmo layout em cada Tab.

Comment: Posso converter uma Activity pra Fragment?